# jQuery Mobile DOM Page Reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I find that jQuery mobile is not reusing loaded pages.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if (activePage.hasClass("search-page")) {

        var controller = activePage.data("controller");

        if (!controller) {

            controller = new SearchController(activePage);
            activePage.data("controller", controller);
        }

        controller.loadPage();
    }
});
```

Then later...

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "search.html");
```

which is an html document that contains

```
<div data-role="page" class="search-page">
```

However, upon each navigation to search.html, activatePage.data("controller") is null and so I reinitialize my SearchController.

I thought jQuery mobile reused pages already loaded into the DOM?

Comment: Add `data-dom-cache="true"` to search.html page div if you want to keep it in dom. External pages are removed once hidden, they are not cached.

Comment: What is considered an external page?

Comment: Any page loaded via Ajax, e.g. Search.html is an external page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile works with two distinct page template solution.

- **Multi opage** - Where every page is part of a single HTML file
- **Multi HTML**  - Where single page is part of a single HTML file

You can of course mix those templates.

When jQuery Mobile is initialized for the first time initial HTML file is fully loaded into the DOM. This content will stay in the DOM until page is refreshed (or you remove it forcefully which is bad decision).

Every other HTML page will get loaded when you transition to it and it will get removed as soon as you transition from it. Basically it will stay alive in the DOM as long as is active.

So, in few words, only pages found in initial HTML file will permanently stay in the DOM, everything else will get loaded/removed as you activate it.